# Chmod in Python - [Errno 1] Operation not permitted

Tags: python, macos, chmod

I'm trying to modify an application in my /Applications folder on OS X. I need to get read and write permissions, so I currently have:

```
os.chmod(appDir, 0644)
```

where appDir is the directory of my app. However, whenever I run the program, I get the error:

```
OSError: [Errno 1] Operation not permitted: '/Applications/Simplenote.app'
```

I would try **sudo**, but how would you enter the password through Python? (this is a Python script by the way)

Any help is appreciated.

Comment: i guess you need to sudo the script itself, after that you type your password and it runs

Comment: Side-note: Do you want it to only be read/write? Usually you want executables to be executable too, e.g. `0o755` (the `0o` prefix makes it compatible with both Py2 and Py3).

Comment: @minitoto Can you give me an actual code example of it? I've never worked with os functions before.

Comment: Write your python script, open command line and run it sudo python script.py

Comment: @minitoto makes a good suggestion, however note the combination of unlimited permission and automation is a recipe for greatly increasing the scope of mistakes. Be careful not to delete your stuff :)

Answer (score 0):

If you are trying to run the script from a web site, change the target folders/files to be owned by the web user, e.g. www-data. `sudo chown www-data * -R` That fixed it for me.